# Node.JS "Uncaught TypeError: util.TextEncoder is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, browserify

I have used browserify to bundle up my js files. I get an error of the form

```
Uncaught TypeError: util.TextEncoder is not a constructor
    at Object.1.util (bundle.js:3)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at r (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

Here are my initial few lines of bundle.js

```
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var util = require('util');
var utf8 = new util.TextEncoder();

let secretDataTxt=document.querySelector(`#SecretData`);
let passwordTxt=document.querySelector(`#Password`);
let result=document.querySelector(`#Result`);

let encryptBtn=document.querySelector(`#encrypt`);
```

Can someone please help me with this error?

EDIT: Here is a working example

```
const util = require('util');
const utf8 = new util.TextEncoder();

console.log(utf8.encode("Hello"));
```

Output: Uint8Array(5) [ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 ]

Comment: This is the offending line: var utf8 = new util.TextEncoder();
Are you sure that *util* is defined?

I'm not familiar with browserify, but normally `require` is not available on the window object, (just in node.js)

Comment: @paroxyzm I don't think there is a problem with util. It works fine elsewhere.

Comment: Try this code, it will error with the same message as yours
const x = undefined

const r = new x()

Comment: @paroxyzm Yeah it does but what is that got to do with util ?

Comment: if util does not have TextEncoder then you'll have this error.
So maybe utils is malformed?

Your code behaves exactly as if util  was defined like this
util = {}

Comment: @paroxyzm I don't think so. Util works well in my IDE (which uses NodeJS). I guess there is some issue with browserify implementation. If util was defined as {} then the error specifies that util.TextEncoder() is not a function. Whereas my question contains the error that it isn't a constructor.

Comment: Please double check your last statement:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBArlAlgGwFwwIZgJ4wLwwDeAsAFAxkC+ZNpoksATvjGAKYDu8SyAdGOACiAD0TREYAOYAKAJQBuIA

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. I would look at my browserify implementation once.

Answer (score 3):

Try by running `npm install text-encoding`

and paste this code wherever it gives you the error:

```
const TextEncodingPolyfill = require('text-encoding');
Object.assign(global, {
  TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
  TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
});


const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
```